# issues "using ls -al --full-time" in OSX

Tags: macos, bash, ls

**--full-time** is a handy little option for **ls** but it doesn't work when used in a batch file.

**ls -al --full-time** when used at the command prompt yields a an expanded date and time:

> 2012-01-16 18:56:00.000000000

used in a bash script I got this:

> **ls: illegal option -- - usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]**

is there any way around this.

Comment: Want to show us your script? I'm not having any problems with that command in a bash file.

Comment: I wish I knew a way to format `ls` datetimes (I'd rather see ISO-8601). Apple's BSD manual for `ls` seems to offer nothing for formatting datetimes, other than changing timezone and sorting by datetime rather than alpha. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html

Answer (score 35):

for native `ls` command, option `-T` seems to be the alternative of `--full-time`, and it expands to seconds, example as below:

```
>$  ls -lT
-rw-r--r--   1 raison staff     197 Feb 14 09:12:56 2013 1.c
-rw-r--r--   1 raison staff    1174 Mar  8 09:34:49 2013 1.s
-rw-r--r--   1 raison staff     993 Feb  5 14:44:09 2013 1.x86.s
```

Answer (score 5):

The BSD (Mac OS X) version of `ls` (installed as `/usr/bin/ls`) does not support the `--full-time` option.

The GNU version of `ls` does support `--full-time`.  I have the GNU `ls` installed in a different directory (`/usr/gnu/bin/ls`).

- Are you sure that you have GNU `ls` on your machine at all?
- If so, are you sure your PATH includes the directory where it is installed ahead of `/usr/bin` when you run scripts?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ uname -rs
Darwin 11.4.2
$ ls -al --full-time
ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]
```

Are you sure your `ls` isn't actually `gls` installed by homebrew?

Comment: I'm on Darwin 12.2.0 and see the same thing--the invocation never works.

Comment: Actually, I tried gls and it worked fine in a script.